# How to set xaxis label according my json result data?

Tags: highcharts

**Hi. I have this json result:**

```
([{"total": 2797, "date": "13.12"}, {"total": 3252, "date": "14.12"}, {"total": 771, "date": "15.12"}, {"total": 669, "date": "16.12"}, {"total": 2962, "date": "17.12"}, {"total": 1, "date": "19.12"}])
```

I want set the date value on my xaxis label, but I'm not able to do that.
Help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the date 13.12 supposed to be?

Comment: This is the date 12.13.2012 truncated, but on brazilian standard, the day comes first. And this is the value that I want to show in my xaxis Labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all series points are going to be one-day increments and you want the xAxis date format to be day.Month you can do the following using the `Date.UTC` method:

```
Date.UTC(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,millisec)
```

The `year`, `month`, and `day` are all required. So you will need to get that value as well. Note that months start at 0 and go to 11.

Then your data, in HighCharts format, would look like:

```
[Date.UTC(2012, 11, 13), 2797], [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 14), 3252], [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 15), 771], [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 16), 669], [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 17), 2962], [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 18), null], [Date.UTC(2012, 11, 19), 1]
```

To get your chart to plot cleanly you will also need to set a value for 12.18 which your currently do not do. I set it to `null`. This chart will not draw a line between null points but you can have it do so with [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.connectNulls). Set it to true if you want to connect the nulls. It is set to false by default.

Now you want to format your xAxis to display dates like '13.12'. You do this with the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) properties. To get your format use `'%d.%m'`. The date format options are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

How you get your data into the HighCharts format depends on your source. There are multiple ways.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Nh2J4/)